# Odd looking "Close" button on error message

Tags: bug, error-message

So, I tried to edit suggest on a post today, and got an error message that it already had a pending edit. Okay, I'll edit later. Sure.

I was about to close the message when I saw something odd:

[image: Image of error message]

It may be hard to see (Sorry I couldn't crop, I'm on a Chromebook and a schedule), but the exit button is clearly not an `x`. It's a `Ã`.

Comment: Good catch! Someone needs to check their editor's encoding...